# Converting Process List to HTML Shows Only Single Process

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0

I have an PowerShell script which contains two variables:

1. `$d`: Array: Get TCP Connection, Just (ID) of each Process.
2. `$gns`: get name of each process in variable `$d`.

```bsh
$d = @(Get-NetTCPConnection | Select -Expand OwningProcess)
foreach ($s in $d) {
  $gns = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $s} | Select -Expand Name
}

ConvertTo-HTML -PostContent $gns | Out-File c:\temp\TableHTML.html
Invoke-Item c:\temp\TableHTML.html
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see, the result shows just one process name, which is wrong!
I want to show all process names in the result.

Comment: And with `$gns = $gns + Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $s} | Select -expand Name`

Comment: for loop is constantly reassigning value so there will always be just the one.

Comment: `foreach (...) { $gns = ... }` -> `$gns = foreach (...) { ... }`